# How does recuperation works in BLDC?

Tags: battery-charging, schematics, brushless-dc-motor

Using BLDC wheels is common on electric transport. A wheel is a multiphase motor, where each phase(coil) is separated from power source(battery) with some kind of transistor, driven by PWM-like signal. Almost like in the following illustration: [image]

However, there also exists "recuperation". When you'll manage to press brakes - a motor should turn into a generator and charges battery again. But I've never seen any scheme or model of it.. You cannot simply push current in backwrd direction through fets.

How is this implemented? What approaches do you know (if there are many)?

Comment: It's called regeneration. What makes you think you can't push current backwards through MOSFETs? They conduct in either direction.

Comment: A buck converter from battery to wheels uses exactly the same components as a boost converter from wheels to battery, only the switch timing differs.

Comment: Sure you can push it backwards. You can even push it backwards even when the MOSFET is off due to the parasitic body diode (as well as the external flyback diodes antiparallel to the MOSFET). MOSFETs can only block current flow in one direction as a result, after all. It's more efficient if you actually switch the MOSFET on though so it conducts through the resistance of the MOSFET rather than through the diode. You use the same hardware but you code the switches to fire in a different sequence. Convenient, isn't it?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ah I thought of transistor is like diode, that can conduct in one direction; And with "incase switch", that's operated with current(or voltage in case of mosfet)

Comment: @Toor I thought that diodes drawn to the right of transistors are soldered just to protect transistors from breaking due to self-induction current...

Comment: They are. But MOSFETs also have a parasitic diode (the body diode) inside them that is inherent part of manufacture that can be used for the same purpose. Being parasitic, they are not as efficient, fast, or as soft switching as an external diode, but they are cheaper. Some MOSFETs also go out of their way to optimize the body diode a bit. Look at some versions of MOSFETs symbols. They have a diode that is part of the symbol.

Comment: @Toor So what does that recuperation "brake switch" do? Does it "forces the wheel to rotate backwards?" (And the wheel just pumps energy back to battery, through that diodes?)

Comment: No. Forcing the wheel to rotate backwards is "active braking" where you change the switching sequence to produce a force that tries to rotate the motor in the reverse direction for faster braking. You are literally switching the motor as if you were driving it in reverse. This isn't a regeneration mode and actually consumes extra power. If you stay in this mode after the RPM has fallen to zero, the motor will actually start to rotate in the reverse direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91934/discussion-between-xakepp35-and-toor).